# WPF Validation in view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, validationrules

I've implemented for a lot of my `TextBox` a `ValidationRule` :

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Property" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validator:MyRule ErrorMessage="Must be a number"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

So Is there a way to detect in code behind (or some XAML binding) if an error is raised by a `ValidationRule` to disable my Save button?